# How to isolate database services from pagination and filtering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I'm working on a relatively big project which has a lot of services and querying the database.In most of them, there is a functionality to **filter the results** or **search** in the document or pagination.

I'm wondering how can I have a function or a module to handle all the searching in all services and not having to write the same (kinda same) code in all services.

For example , I have a function to return trending songs:

```
module.exports.get_trending_songs = async (req, res, next) => {
        var searchParams = {}
        var sortParams = {}
        if (req.query.search) {
            searchParams = {
                name: new RegExp('.*' + req.query.search + '.*', "i")
            }
        }
        if (req.query.sort) {
            sortParams = (req.query.order == 1 ? '' : '-') + req.query.sort
        }
        var songs
        songs = await Song.find(searchParams)
            .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
            .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
            .sort(sortParams)
            .exec()
}
```

and I have a function which returns users:

```
module.exports.get_users = async (req, res) => {
    var searchParams = {}
    var sortParams = {}
    if (req.query.search != undefined) {
        searchParams = {
            name: new RegExp('.*' + req.query.search + '.*', "i")
        }
    }
    if (req.query.sort != undefined) {
        sortParams = (req.query.order == 1 ? '' : '-') + req.query.sort
    }
    var users = await User.find(searchParams)
        .select('-password')
        .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
        .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip))
        .sort(sortParams)
        .exec()
}
```

And as you can see, they are pretty much the same! (assume that I return the pagination stuff (like nPages or countOfDocs) by executing the same query and adding `.count()` to it as well)

What's the best way to handle all side-queries (**pagination , search** , etc) in other modules and have the service focus just on the main query? not

Answer (score 1):

Those Mongoose functions return a [`Query` object](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query) that you could pass around easily... so you could write a function that takes in a couple things (like the Model and req params) and does all the common methods, but then do the `exec()` in the main method so you can tack on any extra stuff (like removing the password from the returned fields).

Here's an example of something that might work, but **I have not tested this**... so you might need to tinker with it.

```
function build_query = function(model, reqParams) {
    var searchParams = {}
    var sortParams = {}
    if (reqParams.search != undefined) {
        searchParams = {
            name: new RegExp('.*' + reqParams.search + '.*', "i")
        }
    }
    if (reqParams.sort != undefined) {
        sortParams = (reqParams.order == 1 ? '' : '-') + reqParams.sort
    }
    var query = model.find(searchParams)
        .select('-password')
        .limit(parseInt(reqParams.limit))
        .skip(parseInt(reqParams.skip))
        .sort(sortParams)
    return query
}

module.exports.get_users = async (req, res) => {
    var query = build_query(User, req.query)
    var users = await query.select('-password').exec()
}

module.exports.get_trending_songs = async (req, res, next) => {
    var query = build_query(Song, req.query)
    var songs = await query.exec()
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I kinda knew this is the best way but I have problem implementing this to my project. the examples were very simple , my services are very complicated, I execute some queries to get to a result , now I want to filter that result..Like calling `find()` on a query that already been called `find()` on. +1 for the answer, I'll wait to hear some other opinions

Comment: I want to know the **best way** of querying and writing services that are completely independent of each other, I couldn't find a big production node app to see how they handled all the querying and searching and filtering

Comment: Yeah, this is going to be unique to each application. IMO, this method is good for most apps, but obviously not all. Good luck!